# Is there a shortcut to delete the currently open file in PHPStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

When I navigate to a file deep in directories with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I see that the file can be deleted, so I navigate to the project pane, and open all the nested directories and then finally delete the file, which is annoying.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to just delete the file currently open in the editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut to just delete the file currently open in the editor?

No -- wrong context. "Delete" will work with file when in the right context (e.g. Project View); when editing file (Editor is focused) it will be just deleting text.

> so I navigate to project pane, and open all the nested directories and finally delete the file, which is annoying.

**Navigate | Select In ... | Project View** (<kbd>Alt + F1, 1</kbd> on Windows/Linux using Default keymap)

Comment: `Alt+F1` opens os menu in default Xubuntu though. What's the name of the keymap entry that's supposed to call?

Comment: I always thought that `Navigate | Select In ... ` is pretty clear already ... P.S. I think that in such case you should use "Default for GNOME" or similar keymap instead -- it has more optimized keymap for such environments (P.P.S. Have never used Xubuntu -- not a Linux user so cannot be 100% sure on this moment)

Answer (score 50):

Yes, there is:

1. Press <kbd>Alt+Home</kbd> to focus the [navigation bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigation-bar.html). (<kbd>⌘+↑</kbd> on Mac)

   [image]
2. Then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. (<kbd>⌘+⌫</kbd> on Mac)

   [image]

Even if the navigation bar is turned off, it'll pop up over the editor window.

Comment: Also works to delete the current file in rubymine. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

External tools can solve this.

1. Create an external tool. The program to run is rm, and for the parameters use the $FilePath$ macro. I also tell it not to open the console.

[image: Delete file - External Tool]

2. Add a shortcut in keymap to this external tool to quickly delete the current file open in the editor.

Comment: That's amazing. I had a lot files to delete and came up with the same idea after being not happy with the complex paths of the other answers

Comment: Awesome! Ensure you use `"$FilePath$"` , as the file might have spaces. Worked for me on Linux, not on MacOS where it has files in "Application Support".